# Может ли страница 404 содержать php-код?

Tags: php

Создал страницу ошибки 404. Нужно было там вывести переменную, через echo. Не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP:

```
<?php
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
echo "blahblahblah";
?>
```

HTACCESS:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Может. Как создали, где прописали, какой веб-сервер?

Для апача пропишете в конфиге вот так, например:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /my404.php
```

и вперед.

Comment: Linux server1.hostinger.ru
Apache 2.0 Handler

про ошибку писал в .htaccess
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Answer (score 0):

В настройках сервера нужно указать для 404-й страницы УРЛ ПХП-скрипта.

Comment: Не подскажете как это сделать? Куда лезть то?

Comment: Какой веб-сервер?
Для апача ответ дал alienator

Answer (score 0):

Создайте страницу php и укажите ее как страницу ошибки.
У меня получалось выводить URL по которому обращались.